# Unit-testing a controller method or a template method

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, junit, tdd, bdd

While implementing an operation in a method, I try to break it down into smaller focused methods. Knowingly or not, I usually end-up with one or more controller-like or [template-like](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) methods.

Consider the following example.

Let's assume that the whole 'A' operation as in performA(), including substeps within, is **one responsibility, belonging in ONE class**.

```
public class OperationAPerformer{

    public void performA(A a){
          E1 e1 = performSubstep_b(a.getB1() )
          performSubstep_e(e1, a.getE2() )
    }

    protected E1 performSubstep_b(B1 b1){
         performSubstep_c(b1.getC1(), b1.getC2() )
         performSubstep_d(b1.getD1() )
         .....
         return e1;
    }

    protected void performSubstep_c(C1 c1, C2 c2) {...//simple stuff, no more method invocations}

    protected void performSubstep_d(D1 d1) {...//simple stuff, no more method invocations}

    protected void performSubstep_e(E1 e1, E2 e2) {...//simple stuff, no more method invocations}

}
```

It is fairly straightforward to test methods like performSubstep_c, performSubstep_d, performSubstep_e by creating text fixures of C1, C2, D1, E1, and E2.

However, testing controller kind of methods like performA or performSubstep_b gets relatively complicated resulting in cluttered and duplicated code.

For instance, to test a method like performA, I will have to create a test fixture that satisfies the entire call hierarchy i.e. I need to mock/stub/fake the instances of A1, B1, C1, C2, D1, E2, what not, and set the object graph.

*As I move up the hierarchy of a **method chain with in the same class**, unit-testing gets exponentially cluttered, tedious, and no-fun.*

I'm just wondering whether the design itself is not testable?

Could you please shed some light on **how to test certain scenarios involving controller methods**. Should I revisit the design or test it differently?

Answer (score 3):

If each of these protected methods contains a significant amount of logic, the class being tested probably has too many responsibilities (see [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)).

You can extract the behaviour of each significant method into its own class, or even extract all the methods into a single class. These classes can then be injected into the class under test and mocked to allow you just to test the functionality of performA in isolation.

As an additional bonus you can then simply test the newly extracted classes in isolation from each other too.

This would lead to a much more object oriented and testable design.

Answer (score 0):

There are **options you have to increase testability** of your code:

1. In order to test code easily it should be written testable. **Check your code if it has the following code-smells** since it is developer's responsebility to write testable code. There is a good article [Guide: Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) ([pdf book](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf)) that highlights common code-smells (flaws):

   - [Flaw #1: Constructor does Real Work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)
   - [Flaw #2: Digging into Collaborators](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-digging-into-collaborators/)
   - [Flaw #3: Brittle Global State & Singletons](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/)
   - [Flaw #4: Class Does Too Much](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-class-does-too-much/)

   Even more information you can find in the book ["Working Effectively with Legacy Code"](http://www.informit.com/store/working-effectively-with-legacy-code-9780131177055?aid=15d186bd-1678-45e9-8ad3-fe53713e811b) by Michael Feathers.
2. Your controller might have too many responsibilities and [**extract class refactoring**](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) **can be performed** to reduce complexity of of your unit tests.
3. If all substeps cannot be extracted into subclass and form single responsebility of your class `OperationAPerformer`, then **it is better to introduce creation of you** `class under test` within `TestInitialize()`/ `TestSetup()` method**. Since it is invoked before every test, it is enough to write this code once only. Test-specific set-up should be written in every test though.